# Can I get Travis-like GitHub integration while running tests on a local server?

Tags: security, github, automated-tests, travis-ci

I want to run our automated test suite on our own infrastructure, e.g. to run additional tests against non-public data. I'd like to ensure these tests run in the course of every GitHub pull-request (reporting on commits) to factor into merge decisions.

Can I configure Travis-CI to SSH into a local test server, without leaking credentials? Alternatively, is it possible for us to ourselves host a stripped back instance of Travis, or similar software components, in order to get the same GitHub integration experience?

Comment: An alternative approach is to shift focus from on-premise infractructure to cloud infrastructure and from on-premise private data to cloud private data. More specifically, ensure the access to cloud-based private data requires a credential e.g. private key or certificate etc. Then add to your GitHub repo this credential encrypted by Travis-CI public key. This ensures that only Travis-CI (it knows its private key) can decrypt the credential. And Travis-CI will automatically do that upon any push into your repo. That's how I added Travis-CI to my [repo](https://github.com/winwiz1/crisp-bigquery)

Comment: @winwiz1 So TravisCI already manages a key pair for each repo; I can obtain Travis' public key, use it to encrypt my credentials, and place them in the `.travis.yaml`, Travis will automatically decrypt into environment variables. How does this interact with GitHub integration? To protect against malicious fork pull-requests trying to expose those decrypted credentials.. Do the tests still run for internal branch pull-requests, and is there a way to (selectively?) trigger them for fork pull-requests?

Comment: It doesn't already manage a keypair for your repo. You create Travis account (it's free) and authorize GitHub to grant Travis read-only access to your account. Travis uses it to get the list of your repos and when you need a keypair it will be created as soon as you need it. You put into `.travis.yaml` not the encrypted credential but rather the command to decrypt it. The keypair is tied to your repo and will not work for a forked one. The decryption is a part of CI tests, will be triggered only for pushes, you can restrict for a selected branch only.

Comment: Is the syntax that a string "secure: XYZ" in a `.travis.yml` is replaced with whatever string would be obtained by decrypting "XYZ" with Travis' private key for that repo (which will usually result in a name/value pair, that will usually lead Travis to set a so-named environment variable ahead of running the rest of the commands..)?

Comment: Not sure what `secure: XYZ` refers to, in my [`.travis.yml`](https://github.com/winwiz1/crisp-bigquery/blob/master/.travis.yml) there is no such pattern. It contains a command decrypting one disk file into another file while taking the security sensitive parts from environment variables to avoid leaks in publicly available CI [logs](https://travis-ci.com/winwiz1/crisp-bigquery/builds/149162295). Which one can access by clicking on the green checkmark next to the "Latest commit" on the repo's GitHub page.

Comment: @winwiz1 Oh I see, there are two different ways to define a private environment variable: in the yaml, or in the repository settings. (Only the former case necessitates a layer of encryption; in the latter case you may as well put the plain ssh key in the environment variable?) https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/

Comment: That's right, you can define an env variable in Travis CI settings for a repo. I didn't use it because firstly Travis recommends it for cases when the variable differs between branches (I didn't have such case) and secondly there is a chance one can accidently use incorrect "Show in logs" setting and it will leak.

Comment: Is that example a bit convoluted? It seems to make the encrypted-credential public,   store the decryption-key in secure environment variables, and add boilerplate to perform the decryption during every build. I guess that's necessary for large secret files, but since the credential is only a small amount of data, why not store it in an environment variable directly (and skip needing decryption/boilerplate)? In a circumstance where it leaks, wouldn't the decryption-key also leak (with identical consequence)?